1950s American thriller where heroine is being harassed by something claiming to be her dead brother?
This is a black and white American thriller made in the 50s. Pretty sure I saw it on Turner Classic Movies. We learn that before the start of the film, the heroine lost her brother in an accident...or did she? A stranger comes either claiming to be her brother, miraculously alive, or he tries to get chummy with the family, and you think he might be after the family fortune. At first, it seems like this stranger and his cohorts are scheming to do the heroine in. Towards the end, the stranger suggests to his friends that they take the heroine out into the ocean to drown her and make it look like an accident. Then, the twist is revealed: the heroine is actually the villain, and the stranger is the one being wronged. Before the movie started, she tried to have her brother killed by messing with the brakes of his car. The whole point of harassing her was to trick her into confessing.

You're looking for Chase a Crooked Shadow from 1958 with Richard Todd and Anne Baxter.

A man shows up at Kimberley Prescott's villa claiming to be her brother. But Ward Prescott died in a car accident a year ago, so how can this man be him? Despite Kim's protests that the stranger isn't her brother, everyone else accepts him, including their uncle. Kim begins to fear for her sanity and her life. 

The plot unfolds exactly as you described. Here's a clip:



